# Getting Excel Vba Runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim rownum, startcol, endcol, holder As Integer
    rownum = InputBox("Enter the row that swapping process going to happen")
    startcol = InputBox("Enter the column of the cell you want to swap")
    endcol = InputBox("Enter the column of the cell that you wanted swap with")
    holder = Cells(rownum, startcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, startcol).Value = Cells(rownum, endcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, endcol).Value = holder
End Sub
```

Gives

> Runtime Error  1004 -  "Run-time error '1004': 
>                       Application-defined or object-defined error"

Can't seem to understand.

Comment: First thing I see is that your DIM statements need to be cleaned up...only `holder` is set as an Integer, everything else is a Variant.

Second, you probably don't want `rownum` to be an integer as you could easily hit the limit on it in a big spreadsheet.

Comment: You will also want to assign the parent sheet to every range object: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(...`

Comment: Since you didn't `Dim` the variables correctly, I'm guessing the problem is `rownum` etc get populated with `String` instead. Fix the variables and the rest will be OK

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple mistake. I did not realize that they were variant.

Comment: As per your last question also, I recommend asking questions in the form "How do I ..." or "How to ...". The form of "please help me" is often understood here to mean "do my work for me", even if that's not what you intended.

Comment: @halfer  I am new, as it can be seen clearly. Couldn’t even quote the code properly. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dim your vars properly and use application.inputbox for more options.

```
'using column numbers
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim rownum as long, startcol as long, endcol as long, holder As variant
    rownum = application.InputBox("Enter the row that swapping process going to happen", type:=1)
    startcol = application.InputBox("Enter the column number of the cell you want to swap", type:=1)
    endcol = application.InputBox("Enter the column numbedr of the cell that you wanted swap with", type:=1)
    holder = Cells(rownum, startcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, startcol).Value = Cells(rownum, endcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, endcol).Value = holder
End Sub

'using column letters
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim rownum as long, startcol as string, endcol as string, holder As variant
    rownum = application.InputBox("Enter the row that swapping process going to happen", type:=1)
    startcol = application.InputBox("Enter the column letter of the cell you want to swap", type:=2)
    endcol = application.InputBox("Enter the column letter of the cell that you wanted swap with", type:=2)
    holder = Cells(rownum, startcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, startcol).Value = Cells(rownum, endcol).Value
    Cells(rownum, endcol).Value = holder
End Sub
```

The `type:=1` tells application.inputbox to expect a number; `type:=2` tells application.inputbox to expect a string.